Rider 2020 при работе в Unity ругается на некоторый синтаксис из последних версий C#

При наведении на подчеркивания new() выдает:
"tuple must contain at least two elements".

При наведение на свойство StartValue:
"Cannot resolve symbol 'StartValue'.

Даже свойство публичное он не видит, якобы, но компиляция и билд и т.п. - все запускается и работает, но во многих местах кода прослеживается подобная проблема с "отверганием" синтаксиса.
Пробовал через GPT решить проблему, тот пишет, что в файле .csproj нужно указать версию. Нашел файл, открыл, там стоит 9.0. Стираю, ставлю 10.0 - автоматически сбрасывается все равно на версию 9.0

Это синтаксис из .NET 5, ему 4 года, он не новый.

Приложите текст ошибки пожалуйста.

При наведении на подчеркивания new() выдает: "tuple must contain at least two elements". При наведение на свойство StartValue: "Cannot resolve symbol 'StartValue'.


Покажи CustomData.
С 10 на 9 переставляет, потому что 9 - крайняя версия .Net, 10 ещё нет, по крайней мере публично. Файл проекта (.csproj) в Юнити лучше ручками не трогать, исключение - если действительно понимаешь что ты делаешь.

